# different values upon executing the same code

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am encountering a strange situation which I'm sure most of us have faced. I have a simple piece of code that returns 2 sets of results randomly. In the code, I have 2 matrices, the rows of which represent a `memberID` and the columns represent the `questionID` and `Level`. I'm trying to create a final matrix which would give me the score of each student on a particular test. Here's the piece of code:

```
encodedID = '123'

#get dataframe having only True,False,NaN
selectedTestsPivotCorrect = selectedTests[selectedTests['conceptname'] == encodedid].pivot_table(index=['memberid'],
                                                                                      columns=['questionid', 'irt_tlevel'],
                                                                                      values='correct', aggfunc=np.max)
#get dataframe having only 1,2,3,NaN
selectedTestsPivotLevel = selectedTests[selectedTests['conceptname'] == encodedid].pivot_table(index=['memberid'],
                                                                                   columns=['questionid', 'irt_tlevel'],
                                                                                   values='Level', aggfunc=np.max)
#replace True with 1
selectedTestsPivotCorrect = selectedTestsPivotCorrect.replace(True, 1)

#replace False with 0
selectedTestsPivotCorrect = selectedTestsPivotCorrect.replace(False, 0)

#replace NaN with 0
selectedTestsPivotCorrect.fillna(0, inplace=True)

#replace NaN with 0
selectedTestsPivotLevel.fillna(0, inplace=True)

#multiply corresponding cells of the 2 matrices and find row sums to get score on test
resultSet = (selectedTestsPivotCorrect * selectedTestsPivotLevel).sum(axis=1)
```

Note that the most basic variables involved `selectedTests` and `encodedID` don't change at all and yet, when I execute this code multiple times, I get either of the two sets of results, let's call them `ResultSet A` and `ResultSet B`.

Have I made an obvious error in the code that I'm unable to spot? Is `pivot_table` responsible for this debacle?

Comment: What is the code actually supposed to do?

Comment: @Ares: I've added comments to the code to explain what it is trying to achieve